# how to display the video files from sdcard in android emulator?

Tags: android, sd-card

how to display the video files from sdcard in android emulator?
I want to display the video file if in sd card foleder some .mp3 files are there.how to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android) example. It illustrate how to play video from SD Card, you need to pass the path of the SD Card in the given method.

Answer (score 0):

the system supply the content provider to query media files.
[MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html), contet uri: 
`MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI //to get auto files`
`MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI // to get video files`